# tvOS: any ready-made REST API component?

Tags: tvos, filemaker

Before i start exploring the deep ends of tvOS, I'd rather turn to the community and get expert advice...

I am planning to write afwo-headed app :

First leg would run from FileMaker Go SDK given the simplicity to f development and straightforward database management.
Second leg would need to be an Apple tv component which only needs to display formatted text on screen, which is sent from the mobile bit described earlier.

Based on technologies i know so far my idea is to use FileMaker go ability to make http get/post requests to a RESTful service. Hence the question: is there anyway to run any such REST service from tvOS which will eventually display formatted text on screen based on requests pushed by mobile app ?

Does that even make any sense or, is there any more 'native' ways to achieve such stuff ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool project. Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/reference/tvmljs or search for TVML and TVJS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [atvjs](https://emadalam.github.io/atvjs) framework for building TVML apps? It lets you build and quickly prototype apps without much noise, abstracting the underlying hassles and complexities of a conventional TVML app.